# Beamer: Blocks at same position from top irrespective of their contents size

Tags: beamer, block

I want to keep blocks globally at the same position from top irrespective of their contents size. Here is my MWE. Any help will be highly appreciated. Thanks

```
\documentclass[compress]{beamer}
\usetheme{Warsaw}
\usepackage{multicol}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Test1}
\begin{columns}
\column{7cm}

\begin{block}
{Block1}
\begin{description}
\item [{A:}] This is
\item [{B:}] New Item
\end{description}
\end{block}

\column{4.75cm}
\begin{block}
{Block2}
\begin{description}
\item [{A:}] This is
\item [{B:}] New Item
\end{description}
\end{block}

\end{columns}
\end{frame}


\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Test2}
\begin{columns}
\column{7cm}

\begin{block}
{Block3}
\begin{description}
\item [{A:}] This is
\item [{B:}] New Item
\item [{C:}] New Item
\end{description}
\end{block}

\column{4.75cm}
\begin{block}
{Block4}
\begin{description}
\item [{A:}] This is
\item [{B:}] New Item
\end{description}
\end{block}

\end{columns}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Add a `[t]` option to the columns:

```
\documentclass[compress]{beamer}
\usetheme{Warsaw}
\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Test1}
\begin{columns}
\column{7cm}

\begin{block}
{Block1}
\begin{description}
\item [{A:}] This is
\item [{B:}] New Item
\end{description}
\end{block}

\column{4.75cm}
\begin{block}
{Block2}
\begin{description}
\item [{A:}] This is
\item [{B:}] New Item
\end{description}
\end{block}

\end{columns}
\end{frame}


\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Test2}
\begin{columns}
\column[t]{7cm}     %new code

\begin{block}
{Block3}
\begin{description}
\item [{A:}] This is
\item [{B:}] New Item
\item [{C:}] New Item
\end{description}
\end{block}

\column[t]{4.75cm}     %new code
\begin{block}
{Block4}
\begin{description}
\item [{A:}] This is
\item [{B:}] New Item
\end{description}
\end{block}

\end{columns}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

The same result could be achieved with `\begin{columns}[t]` for all the columns of a specific `columns` environment or globally with a `t` class option (will affect all frame content).

### Less vertical space before the blocks

This is the result with the `t` global option:

[image]

If that still is too much space, you can remove a little bit more with the `T` options for the `columns` environment, which will align the the tops of the first lines instead of the baselines of the first lines (as `t` does). `T` Can't be used as a global option.

[image]

If that still is too much space, you need to resort to brute force and add a

```
\addtobeamertemplate{frame title}{}{\vspace*{-2em}}
```

which will remove 2em (put whatever value you need) of vertical space after the `frametitle` template.

[image]

Use with caution :)

Comment: Thanks @dcmst for your nice answer. Can we do this globally? Also how to decrease the distance between blocks and frametitle. Thanks

Comment: @MYaseen208 just use `\documentclass[t,compress]{beamer}` and everything will be aligned to the top (including the frames, so the distance will decrease).

Comment: (+1): Thanks @dcmst for your nice answer. Could also guide me how to globally decrease the distance between blocks and frametitle? Thanks

Comment: @MYaseen208 please see the edited answer